# Get all specific nodes inside a specific parent node of an XML using XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have the following XML:

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <link-entity name="ccl1007_studentjourney" from="ccl1007_contactid" to="contactid">
      <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
        <filter type="or">
          <condition attribute="ccl1007_sjapplicantdayattendedon" operator="last-x-months" value="12" />
          <condition attribute="ccl1007_sjapplicantdayattendedon" operator="next-x-years" value="5" />
        </filter>
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="contactid" operator="eq" value="234" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

What I want to do is get all `<condition/>` nodes inside the `<link-entity/>` node and ignore other instances of the `<condition/>`.

Using my example, I want the output to only return the following nodes

```xml
<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
<condition attribute="ccl1007_sjapplicantdayattendedon" operator="last-x-months" value="12" />
<condition attribute="ccl1007_sjapplicantdayattendedon" operator="next-x-years" value="5" />
```

I tried the following but it was only able to loop on the first `<filter/>` tag that contains the first `<condition/>` tag

```cs
XmlNode linkEntityElem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("link-entity")[0];
foreach (XmlNode child in linkEntityElem.SelectNodes("filter"))
{
   var g = child.Attributes["attribute"];
}
```

Comment: This might be caused because some `filter` nodes are nested inside the other `filter` and some are outside off the `link-entity` node. Have you tried debugging to see what `linkEntityElem.SelectNodes("filter")` returns? It might be missing the nodes you want to see

Answer (score 0):

All you need is two xpath queries:

```
var linkEntity = doc.SelectSingleNode("//fetch/entity/link-entity");
var conditions = linkEntity.SelectNodes(".//condition");
foreach (XmlElement condition in conditions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(condition.OuterXml);
}
```

- The `SelectSingleNode`'s parameter will find the `<lint-entity>` node
- The `SelectNodes`'s parameter will find all `<condition>` nodes under the `<link-entity>` node regardless of the depth

  - *NOTE*: The result of `SelectNodes` is an `XmlNodeList` so you have to explicitly use `XmlElement` inside the foreach to be able to use `OuterXml`

The output will be

```xml
<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
<condition attribute="ccl1007_sjapplicantdayattendedon" operator="last-x-months" value="12" />
<condition attribute="ccl1007_sjapplicantdayattendedon" operator="next-x-years" value="5" />
```

---

[Here you can find the working demo on sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=).

Answer (score 0):

Below XPATH statement will allow you to get those conditions in a single call.
Notice the `//` in `filter//condition` to allow the match at more than 1 level, starting from `//fetch/entity/link-entity/filter` which excludes the level you don't need.

```
//fetch/entity/link-entity/filter//condition
```

---

```
var conditions = doc.SelectNodes("//fetch/entity/link-entity/filter//condition");
foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(condition.OuterXml);
}
```